# Ansible user module ignore password quality roles

Tags: linux, passwords, ansible-2.x

I have set some password quality roles in /etc/security/pwquality.conf with `enforce_for_root` on CentOS7 and Rocky8. Everything works good and users are not able to set password which does not align with quality role including root user.
I use a user in wheel group for running Ansible playbooks and problem is password quality roles does not force when users deploying with Ansible. Any idea about that?

Note: passwords in vars file are hashed passswords.

I have tried to add `enforce_for_root` to pwquality but does not work.